# What do those yellow horizontal arrows in eclipse, at the left of the line numbers do?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm talking about the lines that are in the same visual space as my break points. What do those do, and why are popping up and covering my break points?

I am in the Java perspective, i'm looking at the code (code editor view), the debugger is not running, my application is not running. My eclipse is Helios. and I've got RTC tools installed on it.

Thx, you guys are awesome.

EDIT: arrows are not triangles. I wasn't talking about the warnings :P

EDIT #2: a snapshot added:[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words (or in this case, 71).

Comment: can you edit to include a screen image?

Comment: didn't know i could do that, but anyway my problem is solved. Thomas got it.

Comment: When you are writing (or editing) question, you can click CTRL-G to allow you to insert an image file

Comment: I took a screen shot of one; it's posted as an answer (since comments don't accept images).

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The yellow arrows show up next to search results for me.  If you go to the search tab and delete the results they should go away.

Comment: Yup! The yellow arrows in the column where breakpoint indicators also live point to lines containing item(s) matching a textual search and are listed in the search window. The matching item is highlighted in an annoyingly dark grey in the text. One way (mabye the only way?) to get rid of them is to clear the results in the search window (normally one of the tabs at the bottom of the IDE).

Comment: Is there anyway to set draw precedence for the Vertical Ruler icons?  I don't want to completely get rid of them, but I would like to be able to see my breakpoints.

Answer (score 39):

You can get rid of them by going to Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations, then look for "Search Results" and uncheck "Vertical Ruler".

Comment: Great! This option should definitely be the result! This arrow is the best way to get your computer broken.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I can finally see my breakpoints below my Ctrl+H search results.. That has been bugging me for so long (and has been on Eclipse TODO list since v2.0..)

Comment: I finally got tired of dealing with the arrows and stumbled on this post. Thank you so much. Eclipse has, 2000 knobs to turn in 200 different panels.

Answer (score 4):

This is what they look like.
[image: screen shot from eclips]

Note that it's pointing at a blank line.  I also did a search for some string and it did not affect the arrow.  I have been trying to get "Extract Android String" to work from a keyboard shortcut (Mac OS) and may have found some other implicated command.

Edit: I see it now.  Eclipse has more than one search command.  This is not from command-F (find/replace).  It is from control-H (search).  There's a Search item on the menu bar as well.

Answer (score 1):

not really sure what you are looking at...

for me, the little orange looking lines are on the right - and they represent compiler warnings. - you can hover your mouse over them for messages.

when you double click a word in the code, then more lines appear - where that word is also located in the file.

Answer (score -2):

Those are warnings. If you click on them, useful suggestion will be shown to disappear them.

Comment: Warnings show up as light bulbs with yellow hazard signs, not arrows.